# How to automate the process to generate PHP code?

Tags: php

I have this project where I have to generate a new set of "shifts" every Sunday. Right now I'm having the user do it manually by inputting the starting Sunday and then my script fills in until the next Saturday (e.g: user fills in "generate shifts from the [5th] of [June]" and then it'll generate shifts from the 5th (sun) until the 11th (sat) of June.

Shift generation:

```
function generateShifts($day_start, $month, $year)
{
    global $months, $month_lengths, $days, $times, $positions;
    $f = 0;
    $day = $day_start;
    for($i = $day_start; $i < ($day_start + 7); $i++)
    {
        if($day > $months[$month-1]["length"]) //are we entering a new month?
        {
            $day = 1;
            $month++;
        }
        if($month > 12) //are we entering a new year?
        {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }
        for($p = 0; $p < count($positions); $p++)
        {
            for($t = 0; $t < count($times); $t++)
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shifts` (position, day, month, year, time, full_day) VALUES ('". $positions[$p] ."', '". $day ."', '". $month ."', '". $year ."', '". $times[$t] ."', '". $days[$f] ."')");
        }
        $f++;
        $day++;
    }
}
```

The shifts have certain properties such as position, day, month, year, time (e.g: 6AM-4PM, etc.) and a unique ID. Day, month and year are in numbers and are in D-M-YY format (e.g: 6-6-11). I have arrays with their names, short format like Jun, Jul, Aug, etc. (so for the 6th month I'd do $month_names[$row["month"]-1] (-1 because the array starts at index 0, of course) and that would get me "Jun".

Now I want to automate this process so a new week of shifts is generated automatically every Sunday. I can't use a cron job if that is an option at all. It needs to be pure HTML/JS/PHP.

I'm not asking for complete scripts but just for a point in the right direction.

Comment: my guess would be, because the application runs on a server he doesn't control - which is a minor WTF, but it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you will leave your browser running for whole week, you won't be able to do that automatically. Or you could just insert this code somewhere in your site, so users would execute it without event knowing (do not forget to add a check if you need to update those lists in this method).

Also, you could look for "cron job" API providers (site would call your script on desired time).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need this function to be called once a week, but the result of this function is not likely to change.

I can see multiple solutions (omitting the cron):

- either you enforce an admin to do it once a week, else you get an application failure
- or (as advised by Valdas in the meantime, sorry for the double answer here) you do it transparently somewhere in an include file (quick & dirty solution, will certainly fail at some point)
- or (best solution IMHO), you just generate in advance the shifts for the year to come.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sort of cron in your code.

1. Check to see if the job has been run on each page load for this week.
2. If it hasn't, then run the function provided

There's the overhead of checking every page load (could be negligible) and the overhead of running the job that once for that page load.